# Why does my if/else statement to run recursion inside a python function make the loop go twice even though while loop is flagged to stop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have this code which uses recursion:

```
def rec():
     n1=None
     run=True
     while run:
         if n1 == None:
             n1=int(input('first number'))
         n2=int(input('second number'))
         out=n1+n2

         i=input(f'{out}enter r f or e')

         if i=='e':
             run=False
         elif i=='r':
             n1=out
         elif i=='f':
             rec()
rec()
```

The purpose is to compute sums, possibly using the result from the previous sum for one of the inputs. After each numeric input, the user is prompted to input `e` to exit the program, `r` to use the result as an input for the next sum, or `f` to start fresh (ask for both inputs). My idea is to use recursion to implement the logic for `f`.

I test the code by selecting `f` for the first run and `e` for the second run. When I try this, I get prompted for input a third time.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Perhaps you want to set `run = False` inside your `elif i=='f'` case, so that after the recursive `rec()` call returns, you won't repeat another iteration of the `while` loop?

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner, that worked. I would've thought that on the recursive run, when I selected 'e', it would set the flag to False. If you don't mind explaining, why is that run=False under the 'elif i==f' necessary? REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR ANSWER!

Comment: when you call a function, the function-call gets its own set of local variables, so if the recursive call to `rec()` sets `run` to False, that won't affect the value of `run` in the original/calling instance of `rec()` since that is a separate variable with its own independent value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It [is not possible to "help you"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/) here as this is **not a discussion forum**. I've given you a reference that tries to explain the general concept of recursion (even though that is too much for a proper Stack Overflow question by today's standards) because there isn't a suitable question here. Before posting here, you [are expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [isolate](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem and create a proper [mre].

Comment: Aside from that, questions on Stack Overflow should be entirely about **the question, not** you, your experience with programming, your experience with posting previous questions on Stack Overflow, how you feel about the code, your concern about being understood, or anything else like that.

Comment: I tried to edit the question to fix these problems. I think a lot of people do have the specific conceptual problem that you show here, and I think the question could be reopened if the phrasing could be improved a bit more, so as to make the question searchable for others with the same problem. However, I can't really think how to phrase it (and I've been wrestling with issues like this literally for years). I think the underlying question here is really a bit more broad than your specific example; it's about being able to *reason about* what happens when the recursive call is made.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't think the closure is appropriate. OP's question is specific and clear, and the dupe is a ton of information that doesn't pertain to their problem at hand. Maybe the answer is in there somewhere or can be derived from the content there, but they won't be able to reasonably dig it out and easily arrive at a satisfactory specific explanation like the one I posted here. Sort of reminds me of the regex tag closures where every question gets closed against a single regex canonical that has all info you could ever want on regex. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Actually, after taking a look, the dupe thread is a lot of mediocre random info on recursion, which is why it was closed. I wouldn't use that as a dupe target for anything, even if OP was asking "how can I understand recursion in general?" which would be off topic. Such a thread is liable to confuse more than help--it's definitely not fit for a canonical. I doubt OP understands tree traversals or half of the other stuff discussed in that thread. It's mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

A common misunderstanding with recursion is thinking that returning from a call unwinds the entire recursive call chain and returns control to the original caller. This is untrue--you can't skip over any calls on the way back up the call stack. Returning from a recursive call only returns control (pops the call stack once) to its immediate calling function, which resumes running where it left off.

Additionally, each function call has its own set of local variables (state) that no other call can read or modify. You can share data between functions through parameters, return values, and global, nonlocal and class variables, but none of these come into play in your program (that's a good thing; it's good to keep data as local as possible).

In both respects, the behavior is no different than non-recursive functions.

---

With that background context, let's examine your top-level call. When you (as a user) enter `f` to make this block execute:

```py
elif i=='f':
    rec()
```

the calling function pauses execution and runs `rec()` recursively. The child starts out as the parent call did, with a totally fresh set of variables. In the new child `rec()` call, the `while` loop runs and you enter a second set of numbers. Next, you enter `e` to break the loop by setting `run` to `False` in the child. Control reaches the end of the child call and returns back to the caller.

When the top-level `rec()` call resumes, the next iteration of the `while` loop executes because `run` is still `True` within that function. Remember, `run` is a purely local variable scoped to each call, so the fact that the (now non-existent) child call had `run` set to `False` doesn't matter to the parent.

As illustrated by the above example walkthrough, your current design requires that the user enter an `e` for every `f` they enter. In other words, each `e` only ends the current recursive call, not all of the recursive calls.

The easiest way to avoid this is to just return unconditionally after each child call:

```py
if i=='e':
    # the user wants to exit; just return right
    # away instead of flipping a boolean flag
    return
elif i=='r':
    n1=out
elif i=='f':
    # recurse, but when we get back to this call, end
    # it immediately instead of testing the loop again
    return rec()
```

One fewer boolean flag makes for less mutable (modifiable) state, which means the program is easier to understand. Getting rid of `run` is a useful simplification even if there were no bug here.

---

All that said, recursion is fundamentally inappropriate for this use case. It's confusing, non-idiomatic for Python, and will eventually crash if the user tries to make more than about 1000 recursive calls.

Generally, only use recursion for divide & conquer scenarios where the call stack grows logarithmically rather than linearly. (If this makes no sense right now, don't worry--you can avoid recursion completely until you take an algorithms course, which will make this clear).

Since you already have a loop, I'd suggest using it for managing the whole operation. Something like:

```py
def interactively_add_numbers():
    n1 = None

    while True:
        if n1 is None:
            n1 = int(input("first number: "))

        n2 = int(input("second number: "))
        result = n1 + n2

        response = input(
            f"result = {result}\n"
            "  'r' (rerun with result as n1)\n"
            "  'f' (start fresh)\n  'e' (exit)\n> "
        )

        if response == "e":
            return
        elif response == "r":
            n1 = result
        elif response == "f":
            n1 = None


interactively_add_numbers()
```

As an exercise, I suggest handling input errors and type errors. If the user enters a letter where a number is expected, the program ungracefully crashes. If the user enters an option other than `'e'`, `'r'`, `'f'`, the program runs again with `n1` unchanged, which is surprising.

---

As an aside, always format your code with [Black](https://black.vercel.app/) so it's readable to other programmers.

Comment: I've been trying for a long time to find or solicit a proper canonical for this sort of issue, but it's hard to define what the issue is and what its scope is. I *do* know that an answer like this is unlikely to help others even if they do have the same conceptual problem, because a) it's so specifically tailored and b) it adds a lot of detail that's helpful in the way that makes sense on a programming forum, but not in a good reference Stack Overflow Q&A.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's OK by me, it helped OP and may well help others learning recursion. Not every question/answer needs to be canonical. From specific problems, you can often derive general value. OP has provided their code and asked a clear, focused question about why a certain behavior occurs, so all seems well here, and I think my answer is strong, notwithstanding the downvote (not sure why/who though, doesn't matter).